# Vimperator, How to hit i_i keystroke to enter Insert-mode

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vimperator

Following is the Vimperator help about the insert mode

[image]

I have two questions in this regard

1. How the key combination **i_i** should be typed? pressing **i** key once brings me to ignore mode and twice pulls me out and no trace of Insert Mode.
2. Also I want to know what are the second series of keyboard combinations which are recomended at the end of each line such as **i_< C-]** for **< C-i>**. They show up in gray in oppose to the main shortcuts recommended in magenta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<C-i>` is the key combination. `i_<C-i>` simply means `<C-i>` while in insert mode. This is shown in the docs to make it easy to find what a particular key combination does in a given mode.

You can only enter insert mode if you are focused on a text area. Normally when you focus on a text area you are immediately put into insert mode. However, if you use `:set noinsertmode` then when you focus on a text area you will not initially be insert mode. You can then enter insert mode by pressing `i`.

If you are not focused on a text area then pressing `i` will take you in and out of ignore mode.

Comment: Well, I really want to know how to switch to the insert-mode and I would say this can't be a typo since as you mentioned it's repeated couple of time. Thanks for the answer, however I am not sure what you exactly meant by "helping to navigate through the document". In some case there are different grey and magenta combinations such as <C-b> and in gray <S-space> which they both work the same.

Comment: I really appreciate you answer Brett. I have tried this and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

```
:help buffer
```

then you will find **`[count]gi`** is what you need.

Actually, press C-t to shift from `insert mode` to `textArea mode`, or vice versa, press i.  as you know, `i_i` means `press i` in insert mode. So, textArea mode can be considered as a sub-mode of insert mode.